# Can I cancel selecting text in console?

Tags: c#

I'm making a console application in C# and I wonder if it's possible to disable selecting text while holding shift and pressing arrows.

I tried using Console.CancelKeyPress but it doesn't work in this case.

Comment: Did you tried to use hooks for you process? Like native methods that look  like SetWindowsHookEx, UnhookWindowsHookEx? There you can detect which keys was pressed and suppress them as I  remember.

Comment: No, I didn't heared of it I'm looking for it now

Comment: Looks like you try to dramatically reduce usability the same way, "clever" websites try to do when disabling the context menu or disabling selection.

Comment: no i try to enchance that by implementing own selection with actualy deletes and overides if u want because now you can only select and copy

Answer (score 0):

Try to use these methods:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
private static extern IntPtr SetWindowsHookEx(int idHook,
    LowLevelKeyboardProc lpfn, IntPtr hMod, uint dwThreadId);

[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
private static extern bool UnhookWindowsHookEx(IntPtr hhk);
```

And than in hook  method:

```
private static IntPtr HookCb(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
{
    if (nCode >= 0 && wParam == (IntPtr)WM_KEYDOWN)
    {
        int keyCode = Marshal.ReadInt32(lParam);        
        string keyName = ((Keys)keyCode).ToString();  
        //there you can define which  key was pressed and react accordingly
    }}
```

Comment: It says I nead refrence for this LowLevelKeyboardProc and that WM_KEYDOWN not exlist in curent context

Comment: Add this to  your code:private const int WM_KEYDOWN = 0x0100;                    
    private const int WM_KEYUP = 0x0101;                  
    private delegate IntPtr LowLevelKeyboardProc(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

Comment: Unfortunately it does't work :/ HookCb() was never invoked